# Redirect links with specific parent and preserving structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all the links that have specific parent to a subdomain, while preserving url structure.

Example:

```
domanin.com/topic1/subtopic1/subtopic2/
```

redirect to

```
sub.domain.com/topic1/subtopic1/subtopic2/
```

Thank you.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I wanted to ask if it is possible. I was so short because last time my comment got edited to a more "slim" form.

Comment: "all the links that have specific parent" - What is the "specific parent" in the example you posted?

Comment: Hi! All the links that have "topic1" as parent. Only those links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect all requested URLs that start `/topic1/` (the "specific parent") from `example.com` to `sub.example.com` then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)
RewriteRule ^topic1(/|$) https://sub.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This will 302 (temporary) redirect URLs of the form:

- `example.com/topic` to `sub.example.com/topic` (which will also redirect to `sub.example.com/topic/` by mod_dir if `topic` is a physical directory)
- `example.com/topic/` to `sub.example.com/topic/`
- `example.com/topic/subtopic1/subtopic2/` to `sub.example.com/topic/subtopic1/subtopic2/`

Comment: Thanks, "Heisenberg"! It was f... brilliant. Works perfect. Again, thanks!